# Need to change position of element on slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("button.filters").click(function(){
  $("div.second").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  height: 320px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: grey;
}
.first {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
}
.second {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">
    <p>some content</p>
    <button class="filters">filters</button>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <p>other content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please check this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6d1t5jr8/

I need help to make .second div to `.slideToggle` from bottom border of `.first` div.

Comment: add your code / fiddle..

Comment: create a working snippet here or atleast a fiddle to make a minimal recreation of the problem.

Comment: please check it now

Comment: Is [THIS](https://jsfiddle.net/6d1t5jr8/1/) what you want?

Comment: @Abhi, yes that is what i wanted to achieve, but second element must be have absolute positioning of 0

Comment: Check the FIDDLE, the second div is already absolutely positioned, I have just removed `bottom: 0` and moved **div.second** inside **div.first**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem:**

Because of the `bottom:0` in that way, the the height of the `.second` div start from the bottom.

**The solution:**

Try to wrap the `.second` with wrapper. So the slide animation will start from the top.

Like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $("button.filters").click(function(){
    $("div.second").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  display:block;
  height: 320px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: grey;
}
.first {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
}
.second-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0%;
  height: 30px;
}

.second {
  display:none;
  background-color: green;
}

.second p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="first">
    <p>some content</p>
    <button class="filters">filters</button>
  </div>
  <div class="second-wrapper">
    <div class="second">
      <p>other content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Mosh, your code is doing what i want, but for some reason, background color disappear as soon as second element show up.

Comment: `background color disappear` what do you mean? hidden: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QDS0f.png. visible: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Min0x.png

Comment: I managed to make it, I needed to create new div with same background-color. Probably some other javascript code was making this error.

Comment: OK. Let me know if you need more help.